# Sharepoint List Column

Tags: sharepoint, moss

Is it possible for the column to be set as 'single line of text' and in the calculated value portion somehow grab the value from column 1 and column 2?

So the list looks like this:

"col1 text here", "col2 text", "col1 text here col2 text"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to concatenate the text of the two columns, the formula

```
=Column1&Column2
```

should do what you want. For a bit more complex example, if the column names have spaces in them and you want a space as a separator, use

```
=[Column 1]&" "&[Column 2]
```

Or you can use the elaborate concatenate operator

```
=CONCATENATE(Column1, ",", Column2)
```

If this is not what you want at all, please rephrase the question. :-)